# What is the response time of a Samsung UN22D5000NF?

Tags: monitor

I'm asking this in the gaming section since response time of monitors are a big deal for twitch gaming on consoles.

My friend recently bought a Samsung UN22D5000NF.  I can't find **any** information on its response time.  I know it has a Game Mode, but no hard numbers are given when you activate it.  I searched all over the Internet for a response time on the thing, but I can't find any info.

Anyone have any idea what the response time on this TV is?

Edit: I am asking on this site because I think response times are relevant to gaming (I play games that make me sensitive to such things).  Obviously TVs are used as gaming-related hardware - you cannot play on a console without one, so I thought this site would be the right one to post this.

Comment: I can't believe that LCD response time matters nowadays.  Responses should be fractions of a frame (30 or 60 Hz), an interval of time that probably only ever matters at top competitive play (over LAN, as typical internet latency is far higher than that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a specific reference, but every single Samsung LED TV I've ever seen has a 2ms response time (we have several of them, ranging from 32" to 50" in our office).

The "gaming" mode turns off a bunch of the post-processing effects that the TV applies to its image. They're useful for when watching normal TV, but because gaming relies on instant visual feedback, they are disabled in gaming mode.